# Cannot persist state (maintain data) in my flutter app after closing and restarting app

Tags: database, flutter, state, mobile-application

EDIT: i figured it out! i had to await for database to open inside the function... isnt there a better way to do it? since i am opening the database already in the initstate (i dont think its good practise to use async in initstate right, so i cant await my database to open there...)

```
  Future<void> _updateNotesInitial() async {
    await _notesService.open(); //added this line
    final notes = await _notesService.getNotes();
    _streamController.sink.add(notes);
  }
```

i have the code below which works fine. i am still learning btw this is just a simple exercise to make me start understanding how things work. i have another file with a SQFlite service class which is not important for now. the code i cant make work is this one which loses the data when i close my app. After i click the floatingactionbutton to insert a new note, all notes appear again. but i want all notes to appear whenever i open the app. what am i doing wrong? i have seen i can use HydratedBloc but i first want to learn how to do it in the raw way to understand everything.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:notas_aprender/service.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'flutter demo',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: const HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  late final TextEditingController _text;
  late final NotesService _notesService;
  late final StreamController<List<Note>> _streamController;

  Future<List<Note>> _updateNotes({required String note}) async {
    await _notesService.createNote(note: note);
    final notes = await _notesService.getNotes();
    _streamController.sink.add(notes);
    return notes;
  }

  Future<void> _updateNotesInitial() async {
    final notes = await _notesService.getNotes();
    _streamController.sink.add(notes);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _text = TextEditingController();
    _notesService = NotesService();
    _notesService.open();
    _streamController = StreamController<List<Note>>();
    _updateNotesInitial();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _text.dispose();
    _notesService.close();
    _streamController.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextField(
            controller: _text,
          ),
          StreamBuilder(
            stream: _streamController.stream,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return const CircularProgressIndicator();
              } else {
                return Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return ListTile(title: Text(snapshot.data![index].note));
                    },
                  ),
                );
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => _updateNotes(note: _text.text),
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}


import 'dart:io';

import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

const databaseName = 'NOTE.DB';
const create = '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "NOTETABLE" (
  "id"  INTEGER NOT NULL,
  "NOTE"  TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
);
''';
const noteColumn = 'NOTE';

class NotesDatabase_Exception implements Exception {}

class Note {
  final String _note;

  String get note => _note;

  Note({required String note}) : _note = note;

  Note.fromMap({required Map<Object, dynamic> map})
      : _note = map[noteColumn] as String;
}

class NotesService {
  Database? _db;

  Database get _getDatabaseOrThrow {
    final db = _db;
    if (db != null) {
      return db;
    } else {
      throw NotesDatabase_Exception();
    }
  }

  Future<void> open() async {
    final db = _db;
    if (db != null) {
      throw NotesDatabase_Exception();
    } else {
      final Directory docsPath = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      final String path = join(docsPath.path, databaseName);
      final db = await openDatabase(path);
      _db = db;
      db.execute(create);
    }
  }

  Future<void> close() async {
    final db = _getDatabaseOrThrow;
    await db.close();
    _db = null;
  }

  Future<void> createNote({required String note}) async {
    final db = _getDatabaseOrThrow;
    final int id = await db.insert('NOTETABLE', {noteColumn: note});
  }

  Future<List<Note>> getNotes() async {
    if (_db == null) {
      throw NotesDatabase_Exception();
    }
    final db = _db!;
    final notes = await db.query('NOTETABLE');
    final results = notes.map((row) => Note.fromMap(map: row)).toList();
    return results;
  }
}
```

searched manay youtube videos, documents on the web. i have reached multiple conclusions but none showed me how to do it in a simple way like just using a streambuilder and variables/SQFlite

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are not loading all data when the app first loaded.

Create a function to get all notes on init as

```
void getAllNotes() async {
    final notes = await _notesService.getNotes();
    _streamController.sink.add(notes);
}
```

call the function in `initState()` as :

```
@override
  void initState() {
    _text = TextEditingController();
    _notesService = NotesService();
    _notesService.open();
    _streamController = StreamController<List<Note>>();
    getAllNotes();
    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! that makes sense actually but i tried it and it still didnt work. so strange! let me share with you both updated files (i have updated the post)

Comment: can you check if  notes has data in `final notes = await _notesService.getNotes();`